# Serverless Function ARN for Lambda@Edge within serverless.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, serverless

I am trying to work out if it's possible to get the ARN of a Lambda function defined in a serverless.yml file to be used within the same file for Lambda@Edge on a CloudFront distribution.

My code is below, right at the bottom I want to specify the ARN of the Lambda function that I have defined within the same serverless file.

Thanks in advance.

```
functions:

    myLambdaFunction:
        handler: handler.myLambdaFunction

resources:
    Resources:

        WebsiteS3Bucket:
            Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
            Properties: 
                BucketName: website-bucket
                WebsiteConfiguration:
                    ErrorDocument: index.html
                    IndexDocument: index.html

        WebsiteCloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity:
            Type: AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity
            Properties:
                CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig:
                    Comment: website-bucket-cloudfront-origin-access-identity

        WebsiteS3BucketPolicy:
            Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
            Properties: 
                Bucket: 
                    Ref: WebsiteS3Bucket
                PolicyDocument: 
                    Statement: 
                        - 
                            Action: 
                                - "s3:GetObject"
                                - "s3:ListBucket"
                            Effect: "Allow"
                            Resource: 
                                - Fn::Join: 
                                    - ""
                                    - 
                                        - Fn::GetAtt: [ WebsiteS3Bucket, Arn ]
                                        - "/*"
                                - Fn::Join: 
                                    - ""
                                    - 
                                        - Fn::GetAtt: [ WebsiteS3Bucket, Arn ]
                            Principal:
                                AWS:
                                    Fn::Join:
                                        - ""
                                        -
                                            - "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity "
                                            - Ref: WebsiteCloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity

        WebsiteCloudFront:
            Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
            Properties:
                DistributionConfig: 
                    Enabled: true
                    Origins:
                        -
                            DomainName:
                                Fn::Join:
                                    - ""
                                    -
                                        - Ref: WebsiteS3Bucket
                                        - ".s3.amazonaws.com"
                            Id:
                                Ref: WebsiteS3Bucket
                            S3OriginConfig:
                                OriginAccessIdentity:
                                    Fn::Join:
                                        - ""
                                        -
                                            - "origin-access-identity/cloudfront/"
                                            - Ref: WebsiteCloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity
                    CustomErrorResponses:
                        -
                            ErrorCode: 404
                            ResponseCode: 200
                            ResponsePagePath: /index.html
                    DefaultRootObject: /index.html
                    DefaultCacheBehavior:
                        ForwardedValues:
                            QueryString: true
                        TargetOriginId:
                            Ref: WebsiteS3Bucket
                        ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
                        LambdaFunctionAssociations:
                            -
                                EventType: origin-response
                                LambdaFunctionARN: ## Lambda function ARN here
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Ref: myLambdaFunction
```

It looks like you're already referencing Ref in your template. This is referenced here as to what the value will be when you use Ref on a Lambda function:

[Ref Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html)

I usually reference them via:

```
!GetAtt [LambdaResourceName, Arn]
```

Comment: Hmm I have tried that with outputs to test, but I always got undefined resource.
I have however found a serverless plugin that seems to be doing the job I need.
https://github.com/silvermine/serverless-plugin-cloudfront-lambda-edge

Comment: The trick which worked for me was understanding the difference between Lambda function name and Ref name. e.g if your lambda is  called `jimbob` then to reference it under Resource you would use `JimbobLambdaFunction` like `Fn::GetAtt: ["JimbobLambdaFunction", "Arn" ] `  see this example https://github.com/andymac4182/serverless_example/blob/master/src/serverless.yml#L59